# Possible to further minimise the boolean expression: A’B'C' + AB + AC?

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

I need to minimise this expression for use in a logic circuit with a limited number of gates used. Is it possible to minimise this boolean expression any further?
My thought process has been this:

A’B'C' + AB + AC = (A + B + C)' + A(B + C).

I know I must somehow remove A but I am lost on how to proceed.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

*To clarify, the only gates I am permitted to use to represent this expression in my logic circuit are XOR and AND gates.

Comment: To clarify, $A’$ is the negation of $A$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, so A'B'C' is read as each one negated ANDed with eachother.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but you can write this as $A'(B+C)' + A(B+C)$, which is equivalent to $(A \oplus (B+C))'$.

Comment: Would it then be possible to write it as (A ⊕ (BC)')′ ? The logic circuit I am designing only permits using XORs and AND gates (with inverters).

Comment: With just XOR, AND and NOT gates that would be $(A \oplus (B'C')')'$ by de morgan's.

Comment: I think the simplest in term number of gates is A xor (B nor C)

Comment: Translating zwim's suggestion into the gates you can use: $A \oplus B'C'$.